# Can you add custom maps when developing in Android SDK?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm new to Android SDK. I have not even started using the API. I just wanted to know (before I commit) if it is possible to load a custom map and navigate through it? Google map for Android can provide rich details but it won’t show building structures in a big compound. So is it possible to make my own map with corrected coordinates for the building structures in the map and use it to navigate through it?

Answer (score 1):

[location API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html) and [graphics API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html) should help you achieve this.

Comment: I will look more into this  . Thank you for your answer.